# spring jndi datasource setup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, jndi

Hi i am trying to use jndi data source. below is the code

**context.xml**

```
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/SpringMVCTest">
     <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
            maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000" 
            name="jdbc/pluto" password="" 
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" 
            username="pluto"/>
</Context>
```

in spring-servlet config bean is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jdbc/pluto" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/pluto"/>
        </bean>
```

i am getting this error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private app.contact.service.ContactService
>   app.contact.controller.ContactController.contactService; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'contactServiceImpl': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private app.contact.dao.ContactDAO
>   app.contact.service.ContactServiceImpl.contactDAO; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'contactDAOImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   app.contact.dao.ContactDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'jdbc/pluto' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property
>   'jdbc/pluto' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the
>   parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
>   Related cause:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'jdbc/pluto' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property
>   'jdbc/pluto' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the
>   parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: A field cannot have the name `jdbc/pluto`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a bean definition as such

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jdbc/pluto" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/pluto"/>
</bean>
```

The property name `jdbc/pluto` is supposed to match a setter, so Spring expects something like `setJdbc/Pluto()` but that is obviously not correct java syntax.

Looking at the [`JndiObjectFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectFactoryBean.html) it looks like you want the [`setJndiName()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jndi/JndiObjectLocator.html#setJndiName%28java.lang.String%29) method from `JndiObjectLocator` super class.

So your bean should look like

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/pluto"/>
</bean>
```